# Cannot Create Event Handler

Tags: c++-cli, eventhandler

I'm trying to bind an event to a menuitem. It compiles. However, when the 'about' menu item is clicked nothing happens. Please help!

```
ref class MenuEventListener
{
public:
    MenuEventListener (System::Windows::Forms::Form ^form)
    {
        this->form = form;
        this->form->Click += gcnew EventHandler (this, &MenuEventListener::AboutClick);
    }

private:
    System::Windows::Forms::Form^ form;
    void AboutClick (Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ args)
    {
        System::String ^text = gcnew System::String ("This is an about message");
        System::String ^cap = gcnew System::String("About");

        System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show (
            (IWin32Window^) Control::FromHandle (form->Handle),
            text, cap, 
            System::Windows::Forms::MessageBoxButtons::OK,
            System::Windows::Forms::MessageBoxIcon::Question);
    }

};

// Called in the form constructor
menuEventListener = gcnew MenuEventListener (this);
```

Oh, and if someone can explain the concept of event handler, specifically, how one actually uses a "classes events" and its relation to the event raising functions, such as OnClick. I get it but barely. Such wants someone to explain if they would be kind enough.

Edit:
Here is the context for the about menu

```
TextEditorMenu::TextEditorMenu ()
{
    // Create components
    menu = gcnew System::Windows::Forms::MainMenu ();
    fileMenuItem = gcnew System::Windows::Forms::MenuItem ();
    helpMenuItem = gcnew System::Windows::Forms::MenuItem ();
    newMenuItem = gcnew System::Windows::Forms::MenuItem ();
    openMenuItem = gcnew System::Windows::Forms::MenuItem ();
    saveMenuItem = gcnew System::Windows::Forms::MenuItem ();
    saveAsMenuItem = gcnew System::Windows::Forms::MenuItem ();
    aboutMenuItem = gcnew System::Windows::Forms::MenuItem ();

    // Intizlize components
    fileMenuItem->Text = "File";
    helpMenuItem->Text = "Help";
    aboutMenuItem->Text = "About";
    newMenuItem->Text = "New File";
    openMenuItem->Text = "Open File";
    saveMenuItem->Text = "Save";
    saveAsMenuItem->Text = "Save As";
```

Comment: Where is 'about' menu item in the code? This code subscribes to the form Click event.

Comment: So, you need to subscribe to aboutMenuItem->Click event, and your code subscribes to form->Click event.

Comment: What, I'm confused, can you put it in a less obfuscated form?

Comment: I don't know the structure of your program and relationship between TextEditorMenu, form and MenuEventListener, so the answer is obfuscated as your question. Your code `this->form->Click` must be replaced by subscription to `aboutMenuItem->Click`. For example, you can create MenuEventListener constructor which accepts `MenuItem` parameter.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I've managed to correct thanks to your help.

Comment: One more thing, if you wouldn't mind do you think you can just review my code and tell what you would change?